# OSMBuildings building:levels are not working

Tags: javascript, openstreetmap, leaflet

I am integrating Leaflet with OSMBuildings and i am using Classic 2.5D. Everything is working and it is showing 3D building on 2D Map, But The Building levels are not working (I am gone through this docs http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Simple_3D_buildings).

Findout in HTML code as mentioned in `**"building:levels": 12**`, I have added this line to my geojson property.

Here is my HTML code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>GeoJSON</title>
    <link rel='stylesheet prefetch' href='http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.7.3/leaflet.css'>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map" style="width:620px; height:450px;"></div>
    <p>Objects on the map are build from custom GeoJSON.<br>
        Edit the data or paste your own examples here.</p>
<textarea>
{
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [{
    "type": "Feature",
    "geometry": {
      "type": "Polygon",
      "coordinates": [[[72.8999412059784,19.0702453117883],[72.8998178243637,19.0699157606889],[72.9002845287323,19.0700019510397],[72.9003381729126,19.0703416419859],[72.8999197483063,19.0702351717642],[72.8999412059784,19.0702453117883]]
      ]
    },
    "properties": {
      "color": "rgb(255,200,150)",
      "height": 150,
      **"building:levels": 12**
    }
  }]
}
</textarea><br>
<button onclick="setGeoJSON()">Apply changes</button>
    <script src='http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.7.3/leaflet.js'></script>
<script src='http://cdn.osmbuildings.org/OSMBuildings-Leaflet.js'></script>
        <script src="js/index.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

and my JS file is :

```
var map = new L.Map('map');
map.setView([52.52111, 13.40988], 16, false);
new L.TileLayer('http://{s}.tiles.mapbox.com/v3/osmbuildings.kbpalbpk/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
  attribution: 'Map tiles &copy; <a href="http://mapbox.com">MapBox</a>',
  maxZoom: 18,
  maxNativeZoom: 20
}).addTo(map);
var osmb = new OSMBuildings(map);
//************************************************************
var geoJsonBlock;
function getCenter(geoJson) {
  var geometry, len = 0, lat = 0, lon = 0;

  for (var i = 0, il = geoJson.features.length; i < il; i++) {
    geometry = geoJson.features[i].geometry.coordinates[0];
    if (geometry[0][0][0]) {
      geometry = geometry[0];
    }

    len += geometry.length-1;
    for (var j = 0, jl = geometry.length-1; j < jl; j++) {
      lat += geometry[j][1];
      lon += geometry[j][0];
    }
  }

  return { lat:lat/len, lon:lon/len };
}

function setGeoJSON() {
  try {
    var geoJson = JSON.parse(geoJsonBlock.value);
  } catch(e) {}
  osmb.set(geoJson);
  var center = getCenter(geoJson);
  map.setView([center.lat, center.lon], 17)
}

geoJsonBlock = document.querySelector('textarea');
setGeoJSON();
```

Can anybody help how i am displaying my 3D building to levels, roofs, sphere?

Comment: Any relevant errors in your javascript console?

Comment: if i write the code in my geojson property like "height": {"height": 150, "building:levels": 7}, Then it given an error TypeError: geoJson is undefined

Answer (score 1):

See the [Readme about GeoJSON properties](https://github.com/kekscom/osmbuildings/blob/master/README.md#osm-tags-used). The correct property name is *height*, not *building:levels*. *building:levels* is the corresponding [tag](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tags) in the OSM database but it is converted to a *height* property for the resulting GeoJSON data.

Comment: Thanks, But here how would write the building levels. and where i should apply ?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your question. Just use "height" instead of "building:levels".

Comment: "properties": {
"color": "rgb(255,200,150)",
"height": {"building:levels" :7},
"minHeight": 50,
"roofColor": "#FFDA33",
"roofMaterial":"wood",
"material": "material",
"shape":"cylinder",
"roofShape":"gabled",
"roof:shape":"mansard"
} Like this we can use? This is not working ("height": {"building:levels" :7},). How i can apply the building:levels to my geojson properties ?

Comment: Please read my answer again. *Don't* use "building:levels". This is the tag for the OSM database, *not* for OSMBuildings library. OSMBuildings uses "height" instead. See the example in the [Readme](https://github.com/kekscom/osmbuildings/blob/master/README.md).

Comment: Finally my requirement is how to apply levels to my building ? explain and show me an example ?

Comment: Re-code OSMBuildings library to replace `levels` with `height: levels * 3`.

Answer (score -3):

"levels": 13 
will do the trick

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE.  This doesn't really answer the question - please [edit] your answer to expand on how/why this is the correct answer.  See [answer]